Replace special characters ' and " in xslt
I need to replace characters ' and " using xslt. I need to replace them in whole text in xml file. ' character should be replaced to " but only for expressions, in cases where ' is part of word ('s, 'm, 've, etc.) it should not be replaced.
<para ampexmnem="dpa2">
<paratext>The Secretary, in consultation with the Secretary of Health and Human Services, shall, with respect to any items described in this subsection which are to be included in a taxpayer's return of tax, develop language for such items which is as simple and clear as possible (such as referring to 'insurance affordability programs' as 'free or low-cost health insurance').</paratext>
</para>

I tried different solutions, but have no luck, characters were not replaced.
<xsl:template name="replace-quotes">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace" select="'&amp;apos;'"/>
        <xsl:param name="by" select="'&amp;quot;'"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-quotes">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $replace)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-quotes">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(string-join(text(), ''), '&amp;apos;')">
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(string-join(text(), ''), '&amp;apos;', '&amp;quot;')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

May be I missed template's order, but I tried to put these templates in the beginning and in the end of xslt.
Actual result is:
The Secretary, in consultation with the Secretary of Health and Human Services, shall, with respect to any items described in this subsection which are to be included in a taxpayer's return of tax, develop language for such items which is as simple and clear as possible (such as referring to 'insurance affordability programs' as 'free or low-cost health insurance').
Expected result is:
The Secretary, in consultation with the Secretary of Health and Human Services, shall, with respect to any items described in this subsection which are to be included in a taxpayer's return of tax, develop language for such items which is as simple and clear as possible (such as referring to "insurance affordability programs" as "free or low-cost health insurance").

"I need to replace characters ' and " using xslt." I think you mean replace ' with "? Which would be trivial to do using the translate function. Except it would replace all occurrences of the ' characters, not only some. In any case, your usage of  &amp;apos; as the search string makes no sense: it should look for &apos;. But again, if you fix that, it will replace all occurrences of the apostrophe character.

I don't think the problem is defined well enough.
Ostensibly you want to replace an apostrophe with a quote only if it appears at the beginning or at the end of a word - which could be done using:
XSLT 2.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node() except text()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '(^|\W)''(\w)|(\w)''(\W|$)', '$1$3&quot;$2$4')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

But then consider what will happen if you have text like:

an angle of 135° 30' 0"

or:

it is the parents' responsibility


Yes, I need to take care of text like:
"it is the parents' responsibility" too. Quote here should not be replaced.

I am afraid I don't know how to help you with that because I don't know what the exact rule is. It's quite possible that no clear rule can be formulated and that some intelligence (human or artificial) is required to distinguish between the cases.

Anyway thanks a lot for help! :)
